# Alert when selected similar value from multiple check box with the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

When I select for a second time from the below check box with the same value it should alert '**value is already** checked' How do I do that using jquery?

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="1"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="2"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="1"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="3"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="4"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="3"/>
</div>
```

I tried with below code but nothing is working

```
var itemVal=false;
$(document).on('change','.check:checked',function(){
    selVal=$(this).val();
    $('.check:checked').each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==selVal)
            itemVal=true;       
    });         
    if(itemVal==true){
        alert('Proceed');
    }else{
        alert('Please choose same name');
    }               
});
```

Comment: please edit your question and provide the relevant js and css

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('.check').click(function () { 
     if(!this.checked)
          alert("Value is already Checked");

});
```

If you want to keep it checked add this before the alert

```
this.checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.check').change(function(event){
 var arr = $(".check:checked").map(function() {
   return $(this).val();
 }).get(); 
 var sorted_arr = arr.sort(); 
 var results = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
 }
 if(results.length >0){
  alert('value is already checked')
 }
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9a8o37h0/1/

Comment: I have edited this code as per my requirement but its alerting for first time selection. It should alert after first selection and should not alert for uncheck. here is the URL http://jsfiddle.net/vallurisundeep/gue66jat/

Comment: It's alerting even after uncheck the select box.